# HttpClient - dealing with aggregate exceptions

Tags: c#, rest, exception, httpclient, aggregateexception

Hi i am using HttpClient similar to this:

```
public static Task<string> AsyncStringRequest(string url, string contentType)
{
    try
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(contentType));

        return client.GetStringAsync(url).ContinueWith(task => {
            return task.Result;
        });
    }
    catch (AggregateException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }       
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

But i am having difficulties dealing with exceptions. I have added the additional catch blocks just to try and step throw, but none of the break points are caught in any of the catch blocks. I realise using Task the exception could occur on a different thread than the caller so the exception is wrapped in a aggregate container, but i am not sure what the best way to deal with these exceptions is.

For example i make a request to a web service and specific an invalid parameter in the request, and an exception is thrown. I want to me able to catch the aggregate exceptions and look at the innerexceptions to work out why the request has failed and return a friendly message.

So my question is, what is the best way to catch these aggregate exceptions and deal with them?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The exception is thrown by [`task.Result`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468):

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(...);
return client.GetStringAsync(url).ContinueWith(task =>
{
    try
    {
        return task.Result;
    }
    catch (AggregateException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }       
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
});
```

Better: check if the task [faulted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.isfaulted) before accessing [`task.Result`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468):

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(...);
return client.GetStringAsync(url).ContinueWith(task =>
{
    if (task.IsFaulted)
    {
        var ex = task.Exception;
    }
    else if (task.IsCancelled)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        return task.Result;
    }
});
```

If you're not actually doing something in the [`ContinueWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321326), you can simply omit it:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(...);
return client.GetStringAsync(url);
```

Comment: I know this is a old question, but is there any way to get the http status code from from the aggregateexception, like you can when catching a webexception?

Comment: @gdp: Yes, you can call the .Flatten on the AggregateException and then access the InnerExceptions property and pull out the WebException contained within it.