# Mocking a HttpClient TimeoutException

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, task-parallel-library

I'm unit testing my viewmodel command that call a web service. My viewmodel has a dependency on IHttpService which 'GetAsync' method is called by this viewmodel.

I want to unit test my viewmodel and manage the fact that 'GetAsync' returns a cancelled task, which is the case when it's implemented with HttpClient and when an TimeOutException occurs. How can i setup my IHttpServiceMock to return such a task ?

I tryed with TaskCompletionSource.SetCanceled() but i'm not able to tell with which exception it was cancelled...

Comment: A timeout exception wouldn't cause the task to be cancelled, it would cause the task to complete in a faulted state.  Being cancelled means that it willing stopped executing due to a request from a `CancellationTokenSource`.

Comment: Ok, so i have configured the mock setup to return a task created like this: 
`CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(200);
Task t = new Task(() => { throw new TimeoutException("timeout"); }, cts.Token);`
But this task in my 'onCancelled' continuation doesn't contain any exception...

Comment: You are not understanding, an exception *does not cancel the task*, it **completes** the task in the faulted state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use SetException instead of SetCanceled; a thread that completes with an exception still completed, vs. a thread that was asked to stop working.

Comment: Sorry but SetException is not making the task cancelled, but faulted.

Comment: @LoulG. I don't think you can have canceled with an exception; the states look like they are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Andy You are correct, I tried explaining that in my comment on the question.  Cancellation is an entirely separate condition from Faulted, which is caused by *any* exception being thrown during the task execution.

Comment: @Andy You were right, getting a task canceled specifying an exception is not possible as they are mutually exclusive. In order to mimic the behaviour of HttpClient timeout, i had to return a task's TaskCompletionSource with exception set to `new TaskCanceledException()` and handle it into an OnlyOnFaulted task continuation.
As a side note about HttpClient timeout, one can read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19822695/1303737)