# OperationCanceledException thrown in tpl dataflow block gets swallowed

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

For some reason when an `OperationCanceledException` gets thrown inside an `IDataflowBlock`, the block does not propagate this exception to its `IDataflowBlock.Completion` task. Running the code sample below returns an unexpected `IDataflowBlock.Completion.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion`.

However, if the thrown exception type in the block is changed to an `ArgumentNullException`, the `IDataflowBlock.Completion.Status` changes to `TaskStatus.Faulted` and the exception is saved in its `InnerException` property.

Any ideas why `OperationCanceledException` is getting swallowed?

```
[TestFixture]
public class TplDataBlockExceptionTest
{
    [Test]
    public void ShouldThrowException()
    {
        // Arrange
        var block = new TransformBlock<int, string>(i =>
        {
            throw new OperationCanceledException();
            return i.ToString();
        });

        // Act

        block.Post(1);
        block.Complete();

        try
        {
            block.Completion.Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // ignored
        }

        // Assert

        Assert.That(block.Completion.IsFaulted);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to reach Stephen Toub at Microsoft and he was able to confirm that this behavior is by design:

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/src/Blocks/TransformBlock.cs#L186-L190

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/src/Internal/Common.cs#L152-L175

Comment: It should be noted that this behavior is especially problematic when working with the `HttpClient` class, which throws `TaskCanceledException` instead of `TimeoutException` [for some unrelated reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547895/how-can-i-tell-when-httpclient-has-timed-out).