# Xamarin / C#: check for RESTful service call duration

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api, xamarin

In the current xamarin app we are using RESTful services. Sometimes it takes couple of seconds, sometimes it takes 30-45 seconds and sometimes they keep running without returning anything. Until the value is returned user can't move ahead.

I am planning to can keep a timer and wait for few seconds, if we do not get any response within few seconds we can make the service call again or ask user to try again.

I was wondering if there is a better approach to resolve such issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All WebRequests have a timeout duration. If you're using HttpClient, RestSharp or HttpWebRequest, set the timeout duration and then recall your method until it returns a value.

Take a look at:
[How can I tell when HttpClient has timed out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547895/how-can-i-tell-when-httpclient-has-timed-out)