# how to handle xamarin forms http client time out error on Andriod

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, httpclient

The following line of code works fine on emulator but times out when tested on real Android devices
The following is my C# code, any suggestion on how to fix the error.

```
var HttpClient = new HttpClient();
HttpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(200);
var response = await HttpClient.GetStringAsync("https://myUrl");
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I tell when HttpClient has timed out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547895/how-can-i-tell-when-httpclient-has-timed-out)

Comment: Remove the Timeout to catch the exception. The Timeout exception thrown when the timeout is elapsed doesn’t let you determine the cause of the error. We need know what real error is.